# Collision issue in python for import client between Binance and Twilio

Tags: client, collision, binance-api-client

(In python)

```
from binance.client import Client
from twilio.rest import Client
(…)

(…)
client = Client(KEY.access_key, KEY.secret_key) #binance Client
twillio_client = Client(account_sid, auth_token) #twillio Client
```

……

(Questions)

I need to import Client from Binance and Twilio at the same time.
How to avoid collision both import Client?

If I run the code, I got the message as below

> (Got message, run python)  raceback (most recent call last):   File
> "", line 1, in    File
> "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py",
> line 197, in runfile
> pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script (…) AttributeError: 'Client' object has no
> attribute 'get_symbol_info'

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem, I tried looking in my virtual environment site-packages folder to see if I could change the class name "Client" to something different than Binance's Client. Wasn't able to do so, kept getting an error so I found a much easier solution... just use TextMagic! It's free and super simple. Once you set up your free account, generate your key and just make sure to put the +1 infront of your number otherwise it won't work.

https://www.textmagic.com/docs/api/python/